# How can I make a dynamic chromatic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML like this:

```js
$(function(){ // dom ready
    $('tr').each(function() {
       var num = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
       
       var color = /* I want to make a red-color based on the num */
       
       $(this).css('background-color', color);
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>760</td>
        <td>John</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>532</td>
        <td>Peter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>201</td>
        <td>Martin</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>Barman</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As I've commented in the code above, I need to create a *red* color based on the number. I mean a bigger number should own a darker red color. How can I do that?

**Note:** the most dark red color should be `#ff0000`, not more.

---

The final result should look something like this: *(of course down to up)*

[image]

Comment: This is not really a "do this for me" site. What is your question? What have you tried to achieve that and what went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```js
var max = 1000;

$(function(){ // dom ready
    $('tr').each(function() {
       var num = Number($(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text());
       var gb = Math.floor((max - num) * 255 / max);
       var color = "rgb(255, " + gb + ", " + gb +")";
       
       $(this).css('background-color', color);
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>760</td>
        <td>John</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>532</td>
        <td>Peter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>201</td>
        <td>Martin</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>Barman</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Without `gb.toFixed(0)` no background color is set

Comment: @barbsan Thanks, re-added `Math.floor()`. (It did work in Firefox without it.)